# How to verify that at least one of several fields in a model are not blank

Tags: python, django, forms

I have a model:

```
class Artwork(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to='portfolios/image/%Y/%m', null=True, blank=True)
    video_file = models.FileField(upload_to='portfolios/video/%Y/%m', null=True, blank=True)
    video_url = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When a user edits one of these objects, how can I verify the at least one of these three fields is provided with data: `image_file`, `video_file`, or `video_url` so that the verification message appears in the form by the field, similar to what happens automatically if you set `blank=False` and leave it blank?

Comment: See [Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite the form's `clean` method and assign an error message to a field. Here's an example where all three fields get an error message if they are all blank, adapted from the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other):

```
from django import forms

class ArtworkForm(forms.Form):

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(ArtWorkForm, self).clean()
        image_file = cleaned_data.get("image_file")
        video_file = cleaned_data.get("video_file")
        video_url = cleaned_data.get("video_url")

        if not (image_file or video_file or video_url):
            msg = "your error message."
            self.add_error('image_file', msg)
            self.add_error('video_file', msg)
            self.add_error('video_url', msg)
```

Comment: [Model.clean()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.clean) is an even better place for this as it will be check by all ModelForms for the Model

Comment: Model.clean(): "Hook for doing any extra model-wide validation after clean() has been
        called on every field by self.clean_fields. Any ValidationError raised
        by this method will not be associated with a particular field; it will
        have a special-case association with the field defined by NON_FIELD_ERRORS."